# Need help to live WordPress website without database

Tags: wordpress, backup

I have downloaded all files & folders from c-panel root directory but somehow I have deleted/lost the database from my end. So is there any way to get all content from my backup or am I able to live back my website without the database as well?

Comment: You need the database to make Wordpress work. Can you restore your database from your backup?

Comment: you'll need database newer or older but it is mandatory to have at least one database.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to run WordPress without the database.

What's more:

> The only database supported by WordPress is MySQL version 5.0.15 or greater, or any version of MariaDB.

Why it is not possible?

Because as You can read in WordPress Documentation, It is using the database

> for storing and retrieving the content of your blog, such as posts, comments, and so on.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

Basing on that you downloaded files I think You will be able to restore only parts of your website on new installation.